# Linker "Register output" set to "Yes" but Visual Studio does not attempt to register

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, atl

In Visual Studio 2013 Update 4, I created a new ATL project and added some test key entries to the default `.rgs` file.

I verified that <kbd>Register output: Yes</kbd> is selected on the project Linker options property page.

I then built the project and checked the registry, none of the keys were created. I reopened the project from a non-Admin-rights instance of VS and rebuilt and I did not get the error about lacking elevated permissions, which suggests that VS never attempted to register the output (i.e. run `regsvr32`).

Why did it not run the registration program and how can I fix it?

Nothing relevant is printed to the Output window.

#### Update

I enabled Diagnostic MSBuild output and this was in the Output window:

> 1>Target "RegisterOutput" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(EmbedManifest)'=='true' and '$(LinkSkippedExecution)' != 'true' and ('$(_IsNativeEnvironment)' == 'true' or '$(Platform)' == 'Win32')) was evaluated as ('true'=='true' and 'True' != 'true' and ('' == 'true' or 'x64' == 'Win32')).

This is odd. Why does Registration only happen with Win32 builds?

#### Update 2

This looks like a bug in VS2013, as reported here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/801327/msbuild-ignores-linker-option-register-output-yes-for-x64-platform

Comment: Have you tried setting your MSBuild output level to diagnostic? That might reveal some details...

Comment: My crystal ball says that it worked fine but you are looking in the wrong part of the registry.  32-bit COM servers are registered in HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID.  Note the "Wow6432Node" part of the registry key name, it ensures that 64-bit programs cannot accidentally load 32-bit servers.  Google "registry redirector" to learn more.  If that doesn't give you a lead then the obvious way to get better help is to show your .rgs file.  Or to use SysInternals' Process Monitor.

Comment: @michaelb I've updated my question with the MSBuild output.